# Salesforce inputText, inputtextarea, etc rerender error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I do not understand why my values keep getting switched. I think it assigns the value of the first input value box to the first item added and the value fields are not in order of the objects.

```
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!...}" rendered="{!contains(...)}">
            </apex:inputCheckbox>

            <apex:SelectList rendered="{!contains(...)}" size="1" value="{!...}">
                <apex:SelectOptions value="{!picklist}" />
            </apex:SelectList>


     </apex:outputPanel>
     //
```

Sample Output when initially added

```
     Name          Value

     Object2        55   // Added Second datatype: String
     Object1        33   //Added First datatype: String

     Output after save button is clicked once

     Object1        33   
     Object2        55
```

Output after clicking the save button again, the values will keep switching.

```
     Object1        55   
     Object2        33

     //
```

Object are stored in a Map which is changed to a list using map.value() for displaying:

The list is of the subclass objects from below.
public class AccountDetailInstance {

```
    public List<SelectOption> pickList {get; set;}
    public String textValue {get; set;}


 }
```

The list is saved into the salesforce object by duplicating the values and the list gets regenerated based off of the salesforce objects that were saved everytime.

```
//This method loads all the instances for a page
private void loadInstances() {

    instancesMap =  new Map<Id, sObject>([SELECT Id, Name, Value__c, Type__C, content__c FROM sObject);
    //debug account ...

    for (sObject items: instancesMap.values()) {

        subClassObject subItem = new subClassObject(items.Name);

        subItem.Id = Item.Id;


        if (items.Type__c.equals('Picklist') || adi.Type__c.equals('Multipicklist')) {

            subItem.pickList = createLists(content__c); //generates selection list based on values
        }

       if (item.Type__c.equals('String'))    
        {
            subItem.value = Item.value__c'
        }          
    }

}
// This method adds an instance from a selection list which the user chooses in the UI
public void addItem() {

    for (String id : selectedInstances) {

        //creates new sublcass object and adds it to the instanceMap

            instanceMap.put(subItem.Name, subItem);


        }
    }

}
public PageReference save() {
    Account account = (Account) controller.getRecord();
    List<sObject> sObjectList = new List<sObject>();
    subClass subItem; 
    for (subClass subItem : InstanceMap.Values()) {
        //Set all the fields for the sObject
        sObjectList.add(subItem);
    }

    upsert detailInstanceList;

    return ApexPages.currentPage();

}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this from a custom controller/extension. If so, do you have your controller code that generates the list of SelectOptions?

Comment: hey, i just changed the output example to match my problem better, il see if i can post the controller code.

Comment: A common cause of varying order is when some intermediate logic makes use of a map and the key isn't just a primitive. So yes, post the code that builds the list that has order problems.

Comment: Absolutely. If the list is re-created from Map.values, then the order isn't guaranteed to be consistent between client-server roundtrips.

Comment: I see, I think  my problem is surely with the Map.Value() but since I have to use a map how do I preserve the order?

Comment: Also since salesforce doesnt have like linkedHashMaps or TreeMap, i do not know how to keep the order consistent. Is it possible to write code to keep consistent orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully follow your logic, but hopefully this answer will allow you to address the problem in your own code.

As you mention in your comment, Apex does not have order-retaining maps. (You can create them yourself but the lack of generics in Apex limits the attractiveness of that approach.)

But you can use more than one collection type side-by side e.g. a List and a Map:

```
private List<SObject> sobList;
private Map<Id, SObject> sobMap;
private void loadInstances() {
    sobList = [select Id, Name, ... from SObject order by Name];
    sobMap = new Map<Id, SObject>();
    for (SObject sob : sobList) {
        sobMap.put(sob.Id, sob);
    }
}
```

and refer to the list when order matters and use the map where you want to do a quick lookup (or avoid duplicates). Also note the explicit `order by` in the SOQL.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I will be trying to implement a similar solution.Hopefully it works out.

Comment: It worked! you are the best :)